# What kind of Java design model is this example?

Tags: java, jsp, model

I am developing a JSP project in Eclipse and have chosen File -> New -> Other -> Web -> Dynamic Web Project.

In my project I have the following files:

1. NewFile.jsp (This is where my presentation logic resides)
2. NewFile.css
3. JavaBean.java (My java class) (This is where my business logic resides)

In my java class there's a method which pulls data from a MySQL database and some attributes to communicate between the .jsp file and the java class itself.

My JSP file looks like the following:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" import="controllerbean.JavaBean"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<%
JavaBean.MyMethod();
if (JavaBean.sqlresult != null)
{
    out.println(JavaBean.sqlresult);
}
%>

</body>
</html>
```

What kind of Java design model is this example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model 1 (btw is this homework?)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_1

Comment: No, this is not homework. I am just trying to get my head around the MVC/Model patterns. Why? :-)

Comment: oops sorry, its just that mixing presentation, business and persistence logic is pretty much considered obsolete or bad practice for serious apps. still may be a good place to start

Answer (score 0):

You have Model, View pattern.

Reasoning:

Your Java code does the work of both Model and Controller

Why Model ? Because it does database interaction, holds on to the data

Why Controller ? Because it speaks to the jsp directly

Your jsp and css combines your presentation logic.

Though you should try to move to MVC 2 architecture like JSF, Struts e.t.c.

Edit:

Some reading

[Explained](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/patterns/MVC-detailed.html)

[MVC2](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-1999/jw-12-ssj-jspmvc.html)

[Very good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970504/examples-of-java-mvc-model-2-architecture)