# How to retrieve data from SQL Server every time through method on Java , JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, javascript-objects, dom-events

I want to retrieve new  data every second from SQL server and show it on Chart. I can refresh chart every time on java script like

```
<script>
 window.setInterval(function(){
  // refresh chart ...
     }, 20000);
```

However data1, data2 is not updated through. I inserted some new lines on Database

Here is overall inside jsp file

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ page import="java.sql.ResultSet" %>
    <%@ page import="java.sql.SQLException" %>
    <%@ page import="java.sql.Statement" %>
    <%@ page import="java.sql.Connection" %>
    <%@ page import="java.sql.DriverManager" %>
    <%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
    <%@ page import="java.util.Map" %>
    <%@ page import="java.util.HashMap" %>
    <%@ page import="java.util.Set" %>
    <%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
    <%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>
    <%@ page import="com.google.gson.Gson"%>
    <%@ page import="com.google.gson.JsonParser"%>
    <%@ page import="com.google.gson.JsonObject"%>
    <%@ page import="com.google.gson.JsonElement"%>
    <%@ page import="com.google.gson.JsonObject"%>
        <%
        Gson gsonObj = new Gson();
        Map<Object,Object> map = null;
        List<String>data1=new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String>data2=new ArrayList<String>();
        List<Map<Object,Object>> list = new ArrayList<Map<Object,Object>>();
        String dataPoints = null;
        Connection connect = null;
        Statement s = null;
        String BuildIP ="X.X.X.X";
        String TCP="XXXX";
        String Instancename="ABC";
        String Db="DATA";
        String UID="sa";
        String PSW="123456";
    String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://"+BuildIP+":"+TCP+";instance="+Instancename+";databaseName="+Db+";user="+UID+";password="+PSW+"";
        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            connect =  DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
            s = connect.createStatement();
            String sql = "select top 10 * from TIMEDATA1 order by RecordID desc";
            ResultSet resultSet = s.executeQuery(sql);
            String xVal, yVal;
                while( resultSet.next()) { 

                    xVal = resultSet.getString(1);
                    yVal = resultSet.getString(2);
                    map = new HashMap<Object,Object>(); map.put("x", Double.parseDouble(xVal)); map.put("y", Double.parseDouble(yVal)); list.add(map);
                    dataPoints = gsonObj.toJson(list);
                    data1.add(xVal);
                    data2.add(yVal);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                out.println(e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                if(s!=null){
                    s.close();
                    connect.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                out.println("<div  style='width: 50%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-top: 200px;'>Could not connect to the database. Please check if you have SQL Connector installed on the machine - if not, try installing the same.</div>");
                dataPoints = null;
            }
        %>
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html> 
    <head> 
    <script
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.bundle.js"> 
    </script> 
    </head> 
    <body> 

    <canvas id="myChart" width="900" height="400"></canvas> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    window.setInterval(function(){


    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart"); 

    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, { 
    type: 'bar', 
    data: { 
        //labels: ["CS", "IT" , "ECE" , "EE", "ME", "BE"], 
        labels:<%out.print(data1);%>,
        datasets: [ 
        { label: '# of students', 
            data:<%out.print(data2);%>,
        //  data: [105,124,78,91,62,56], 
            backgroundColor :['rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)', 
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)', 
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)', 
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)', 
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)', 
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)' 
    ], 

    borderColor: [ 
                    'rgba(255,99,132,1)', 
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)', 
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)', 
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)', 
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)', 
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)' 
                ], 
    borderWidth : 1 
        } 
        ] 
    }, 
    options: { 
            scales: { 
                yAxes: [{ 
                    ticks: { 
                        beginAtZero:true 
                    } 
                }] 
            } 
        } 
    }); 
    }, 1000);
        </script> 

    </body> 
    </html>
```

Please help me how to get new data from SQL Server every second

Answer (score 0):

You are using and old model of arcitecture (Model 1), I think it has at least 20 years!

if you want to jump forward in the future of 10 years you can use a different model: Model 2. You can read more everywhere, for example [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/model-1-and-model-2-mvc-architecture) or [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970504/examples-of-java-mvc-model-2-architecture).

Using Model 2 you can implement a web service called asynchronously (via ajax), polling your data and updating only a single part of your page.

If you wanto to jump forward in the future of 20 years you can use [WebSockets](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/websocket.htm)

**EDIT :**

Use a [datasource and a connection pool](https://www.baeldung.com/java-connection-pooling): a connection opened via DriverManager is used from a standalone application (and not always)

Comment: Before I post this question I googled a lot to find solution But there are no same with my situation . I also hurry up to do it. If you know which instruction same same please share . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing client side with server side in a wrong way.

```
data:<%out.print(data2);%>,
```

When you call this jsp the code on top executes once, then after body rendering, the function inside setInterval executes every 1 second, but it takes always the same data.

IMHO you can revise your code splitting it in 2 parts:

- jsp code goes in a servlet (or a jsp) that returns a json string using response.setContentType("application/json");
- html javascript code must do an ajax call to invoke such servlet to get the data

Comment: Before I post this question I googled a lot to find solution But there are no same with my situation . I also hurry up to do it. If you know which instruction same same please share . Thank you